# How can I change the design for a single cms page content heading?

Tags: cms, design

I've been trying to set a custom design for a cms page, but I can't seem to figure out how to reference it.  I just need to add a class to it, so I created a template as in the instructions [here](http://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-change-the-header-of-magento-cms-page/) only I want to change the Content Heading, not the page header.

What block should I be referencing?

I tried this:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>cms/headers/custom.phtml</template></action> 
</block> 
</reference>
```

But that also displayed my custom design at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got it, "page_content_heading". You just need to reference it rather than adding it over again

```
<reference name="page_content_heading">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>cms/headers/custom.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

On a similar topic, if you're literally just looking to add a class to the file, may I recommend using the original template file (copied to your theme of course) and adding the class conditionally.

Somewhere in your template file:

```
<?php if ($this->getData('added_class')): ?><?php echo $this->getData('added_class') ?><?php endif ?>
```

Then, you can add whatever class you want with a XML layout update:

```
<reference name="page_content_heading">
    <action method="setData"><key>added_class</key><val>YOUR_CLASS_NAME</val></action>
</reference>
```

That way you don't need to have a whole bunch of different .phtml files for the same purpose should you need to start adding different classes per CMS page.

On ANOTHER note... you could just add a class to the body tag without the need to customize any view script.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="addBodyClass"><class>YOU_CLASS_NAME</class></action>
</reference>
```

Then in your CSS file target the page header using the body class as well:

```
.YOUR_BODY_CLASS .page-title h1{/* style rules */}
```

Comment: I tried your second and third suggestion, but they didn't actually add the class, and I don't know why.  The first option did  exactly what I wanted.

Comment: On a side not of mine, this has helped me in my understanding of Magento greatly.  Thanks

Comment: @DavidWilkins Without more information I wouldn't be able to tell you why approach 2 and 3 didn't work for you, glad you were able to get it with approach #1 though. Please consider accepting this answer if it has worked out for you.